# Ошибка при "git pull" на "PythonAnywhere"

Tags: python, django, git

возникла проблема. При попытке выгрузить сайт на "PythonAnywhere" после добавление изменений в проект Django, мне выдаётся ошибка.

> error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten
>   by merge:
>           mysite/settings.py Please, commit your changes or stash them before you can merge. Aborting.

Как это исправить?

Comment: У вас есть изменения в локальном файле mysite/settings.py?

Comment: @gil9red Я добавляю в mysite/settings.py только одну строку:
 LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/'

Comment: Уберите ваши изменения в файле, повторите `git pull` и снова добавьте. Либо закоммитьте изменения и сделав git pull проведите мерж (git сам предложит это)

Comment: @gil9red Это понятно, но мне приходится в ручную на сайте переписывать все добавления в файл settings.py каждый раз, а не пк его не трогать. Это не удобно и я не могу проверить на локальном хосте какие либо дополнения. Либо же вписывать и после чего удалять, а потом вписывать их на Pythonanywhere.com